# RecyclerView ListAdapter in Jetpack: Bound and model items discrepancy?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to refresh/update a RecyclerView that uses a ListAdapter + bi-directional data binding, however it looks like upon the first update, unchanged model items (as decided by `DiffUtil.ItemCallback.areContentsTheSame()`) in the list submitted through `submitList()` are not bound to the existing views and changes resulting from user actions (e.g. clicking a checkbox) are not reflected in the ListAdapter's currentList, thus subsequent RecyclerView data updates through `submitList()` are broken. Am I missing something really obvious?

Relevant code excerpts are found below.

item_rule.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="rule"
            type="com.RuleModel" />
    </data>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    ....
```

RuleViewAdapter.java

```java
package com;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.ItemRuleBinding;
import com.RuleModel;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java9.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class RuleViewAdapter extends ListAdapter<RuleModel, RuleViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
  private static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<RuleModel> DIFF_CALLBACK =
      new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<RuleModel>() {
        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(RuleModel oldItem, RuleModel newItem) {
          return Objects.equals(oldItem.getSectionName(), newItem.getSectionName());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(RuleModel oldItem, RuleModel newItem) {
          return Objects.equals(oldItem.getName(), newItem.getName())
              && oldItem.getChecked() == newItem.getChecked();
        }
      };


  RuleViewAdapter() {
    super(DIFF_CALLBACK);
  }

  @Override
  public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    ItemRuleBinding binding =
        DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.item_rule, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(binding);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.binding.setRule(getItem(position));
    holder.binding.executePendingBindings();
  }

  CompletableFuture<Void> replace(List<RuleModel> rules) {
    CompletableFuture<Void> result = new CompletableFuture<>();
    submitList(rules, new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        result.complete(null);
      }
    });
    return result;
  }

  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final ItemRuleBinding binding;

    ViewHolder(ItemRuleBinding binding) {
      super(binding.getRoot());
      this.binding = binding;
    }
  }
}
```

List update

```java
          List<RuleModel> rules = new ArrayList<>(result.length());
          while (it.hasNext()) {
            try {
              JSONObject ruleObject = result.getJSONObject(it.next());
              rules.add(new RuleModel(ruleObject));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
              Log.e("App", "Failed to get cursor row", e);
            }
          }
          ((RuleViewAdapter) rv.getAdapter()).replace(rules);
```